# ucrtbased.dll and opencv_world310d.dll cannot find or open the PDB files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, dll

i have problem in c++ opencv3.1.0 in visual studio 2015. when i run my code why my program always give output :
`ucrtbased.dll cannot find or open the PDB file` and `opencv_world310d.dll cannot find or open the PDB file`.
I have to try so many sollution but the program always cant find or open pdb file from uctbased and opencv_world310d only.
please if you have any solution help me:)
i very need your help.

Comment: Do you actually have the symbol (PDB) files for those libs? Where did you place them? IIRC the prebuilt binaries from the standard OpenCV distribution don't come with symbols, so unless you built it yourself... Otherwise just keeping the PDB in the same directory as the DLL should do the trick.

Comment: i dont really know i have the PDB files or no and i dont know how to download PDB file except from ms symbol server. but i have ucrtbased.dll and also opencv_world310d.dll and opencv_world310d.lib :(

Comment: The MS symbol server will give you PDB files for MS libraries. If the distribution packages of the third party libs didn't come with symbols (and the standard OpenCV package doesn't), that's it. If you want to have opencv with debugging symbols, compile it yourself with the appropriate settings (most likely just need to pick Debug and RelWithDebInfo configurations).

Comment: ah thank you, now i realize from your  information that " the MS symbol server only give me pdb files for ms libraries" thats why my program still cant find the PDB for OpenCV coz OpenCV is 3rd party and the standard OpenCV package didnt come with symbol:)
but i dont know how to compile it with the appropriate settings, coz my english is so bad so i just get a half or your information :(

Comment: can you give me step by step how to fix it?:(
thankyou

Comment: There's a fairly detailed guide in the [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d52/tutorial_windows_install.html#tutorial_windows_install_build) (note that the videos are supposedly obsolete, follow the written instructions). Depending on what you're trying to do with OpenCV, you probably don't need most of the optional dependencies (TBB might be the only one worth it). The problem with `ucrtbased.dll` seems to be similar to [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1610758/ucrtbased-pdb-cannot-be-found-on-symbol-server).

Comment: thank you very much for your help:)
its so helpful for me, i hope i can fix my problem and you always great in programing ^^
ok ill read it all now

Comment: hello Dan Masek, i had a bad news, i have to implement all of solution in your link but the program still cant open the PDB files from opencv_world310.dll, is the reinstall MS Visual Studio 2015 and Cmake will help a bit?